# Cisco 857 Restore Missing Lines

Tags: networking, cisco, cisco-ios

I have backup up my Cisco 857 using HyperTerminal and the Cisco Serial Cable. The settings are:

9600 baud, 8 data bits, 1 stop bit, No parity, no flow control.

I have then tried to restore onto another Cisco 857 again using the HyperTerminal "Paste To Host" command.

Occasionally the pasting of commands seems to overrun the capability of the 857 to handle them and lines are being missed. I have tried adding flow control but this doesnt seem to have had any effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In hyperterminal go to <kbd>File</kbd> => <kbd>Properties</kbd> => <kbd>Settings</kbd> => <kbd>ASCII setup</kbd> and enter a line delay of 1000msec. Set it higher if you're still having issues.

Answer (score 0):

All cisco routers have limits on what they can receive on input without overflowing buffers and it all depends a lot on baud speed. Try increasing the baud speed to 115200.

TBH though you will never get perfect results here with large cut and paste. The most reliable approach is to use something like expect, where you wait for the router command line before sending the next line.